# find documents having a specific count of matches array

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I've searched high and low but not been able to find what i'm looking for so apologies if this has already been asked.

Consider the following documents

```
{
    _id: 1,
    items: [
        {        
            category: "A"
        },
        {        
            category: "A"
        },
        {        
            category: "B"
        },
        {        
            category: "C"
        }]
},
{
    _id: 2,
    items: [
        {        
            category: "A"
        },
        {        
            category: "B"
        }]
},
{
    _id: 3,
    items: [
        {        
            category: "A"
        },
        {        
            category: "A"
        },
        {        
            category: "A"
        }]
}
```

I'd like to be able to find those documents which have more than 1 category "A" item in the items array.  So this should find documents 1 and 3.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `aggregation`

```
> db.spam.aggregate([
    {$unwind: "$items"}, 
    {$match: {"items.category" :"A"}}, 
    {$group: {
        _id: "$_id", 
        item: {$push: "$items.category"}, count: {$sum: 1}}
    }, 
    {$match: {count: {$gt: 1}}}
])
```

**Output**

```
{ "_id" : 3, "item" : [ "A", "A", "A" ], "count" : 3 }
{ "_id" : 1, "item" : [ "A", "A" ], "count" : 2 }
```